# How to turn of the grouping of markers

Tags: leaflet

When you have many markers and zoom out, the are replaced by a circle marker with the number of them inside.
How can I turn this feature off?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read the [Asking Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add some clarification to your answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50775492/edit). Also add relevant tags so people know what you're talking about.

Comment: You're probably using the Leaflet Markercluster plugin. Check the docs for all the options your can apply to control the clustering behaviour - https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster